# BASH How to check if given argument is command name?

Tags: bash

How, in BASH, I could check if a given argument to a script is a "commands name"?

For example: I know that you can check if a path is a folder with `[[ -d $path ]]` or if it is plain file with `[[ -f $path ]]`.

I want that my `./script` will only accept commands name.

Comment: Would you provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you check if the argument can be executed directly from the shell (for example: if `<command>` is `ls` this return `Yes`, if `<command>` is `las` this will return `No`).

```
if [[ `which <command> &> /dev/null` ]]; then 
    echo "Yes"; 
else 
    echo "No"; 
fi
```

With a simpler `[[ -f $path && -x $path ]]` you can check if `$path` can be executed... but this does not mean that writing the "name of the command" in the shell, it will be executed (you have to make sure that the `$path` is in the $PATH environmental variable.

A simple script that uses the idea above and exit in the case the argument is not a command could be something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ `which $1 &> /dev/null` ]]; then
    echo "Execute the script"
else
    echo "Error! Usage: "`basename $0`" <command_name>"
fi
```

Tell if you need something different...

Comment: @Justin Edited. Can you be more specific on what you need? Could you provide an example?

Comment: @Justin: BTW the "script" part I posted at the end of my answer does not work with folders.

Comment: @Justin: Could you, then, mark my answer as the "right one"? (Just press on the "checked" symbol below the "vote down" symbol. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With `[[ -f "$path" && -x "$path" ]]` you can check if it is a file and it has execution permissions, you can see the full list of expressions in `man test`.

Comment: It still passes everything instead of command, also checked man test but any of the commands helped

Comment: What do you mean with pass? Directories will also evaluate to true with -x, you will need to check also if they are files. I modify my answer with this.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if i understand you right you can try the following:

```
SCRIPTNAME=$(basename "$0")   # in your case -> script
```

Now you can check this:

```
if [ SCRIPTNAME -eq "$SCRIPTNAME" ]
then
    # your stuff here
fi
```

Or do you want something other?